# Place two flags on a question

Tags: support, flags

I saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844760/which-acer-do-you-prefer-why) on Ask Ubuntu and wish to place an off-topic and opinion-based flag on it.

Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: why are people downvoting this?

Comment: There can be multitude or reasons why people downvote on a meta site like meta.SE. It usually boils down to disagreeing with something, or thinking the question is pointless for some reason. Your question does sound pointless, because if a flag ends up getting something closed it's as good as two and there will only be one reason for closure. People might've thought that you've misunderstood the system. But I can't tell precisely what their intent was as I haven't downvoted or upvoted this question.

Comment: @M.A.R. i am deleting the question anyway

Comment: @M.A.R. because I am losing reputation

Comment: Well, in fact you haven't lost a single reputation from this question. It has 2 upvotes which give 10 rep and 5 downvotes which take away 10 rep - these cancel out.

Comment: @dorukayhan it is now November 24, and I have 7 downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back before I achieved 3k rep on Stack Overflow, I found that if I flagged a question for one reason but the question was closed for another reason (e.g. I flagged as *off-topic* but the post was closed as *unclear*, *opinion based*, or *too broad*), my flag would be marked *helpful* anyway. That's the way it works at least for those four flag types (excluding Spam, Rude, Moderator Attention, Duplicate, and VLQ). Flagging one of the four "equivalently helpful" flags was also marked *helpful* if the question is closed as a duplicate.

So that means that picking the "right" reason (or playing "reason roulette") isn't nearly as important as just raising any reasonable flag.

Answer (score 10):

You don't - there is, by design, no way to do this.

If you want a question closed, pick *one* reason - what's the most severe problem with the question is usually the best reason to pick.

In this case, I'd recommend picking off-topic - even if the question was edited to not be opinion-based, it would still be closed for being off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

No. It needs to be closed, and generally you just want one reason to express that. The close reason is just for the user to help them edit their question into shape. There is no reason to flag multiple times.

Comment: what about that specific question I mentioned

Comment: I don't know. I am not a user on that site.